# Focus text input on TouchableHighlight clicked

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a class that I want the text input inside it to focus on the parent being selected.

```
class ListItem extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           editable: this.props.item.editable,
           value: this.props.item.value,
           heading: this.props.item.heading,
           item: this.props.item.item,
        }
    }

    _onPress = () => {
        this.setState({ editable: true});
        this.props.onPressItem(this.props.index, this.props, this.state);
    }

    _onSearchTextChanged = (event) => {
        this.setState({ value: event.nativeEvent.text });
      };

    _handleSaveEvent = (e) => {
        this.setState({ editable: false });
        alert('works');
        //Add in saving item
    }

    render() {
      var editable = this.state.editable;
      var heading = this.state.heading;
      var value = this.state.value;
      return (
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPress} underlayColor='#dddddd'>
          <View>
            <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
              <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>{heading}: </Text>
                {this.state.editable? 
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.searchInput}
                        value={value.toString()}
                        onChange={this._onSearchTextChanged}
                        keyboardType="default"
                        returnKeyType="done"
                        onSubmitEditing={this._handleSaveEvent}/>
                : 
                    <Text style={styles.price}>{value}</Text> 
                }
                {}
              </View>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.separator}/>
          </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      );
    }
  }
```

Ive tried adding

> autoFocus={true}

Ive also tried adding

> ref={this.props.index}

But when I try to focus that it tells me its not defined (this.refs[this.props.index].focus();)

I would like it to be focused when the 'editable' state is enabled, I am not sure why this seems so hard. My background is more in C#, Angular 2+ etc so maybe its just how react is structured is throwing me

Comment: can you try `autoFocus={this.state.editable}` in `TextInput` and try?

Comment: @AravindS Worked great, but I could have sworn I did that previously. Anyway appreciate it! You should write it as a proper answer so I can accept it

Comment: sure.. I will write the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the `onPress` event of `TouchableHighlight` setState `editable: true` and set `autoFocus={this.state.editable}` in TextInput..it will work

```
            <TextInput
                style={styles.searchInput}
                value={value.toString()}
                onChange={this._onSearchTextChanged}
                keyboardType="default"
                autoFocus={this.state.editable}
                returnKeyType="done"
                onSubmitEditing={this._handleSaveEvent}
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Provide ref as a function in `<TextInput />` like this:

```
<TextInput
        ref ={ref => this.inputText = ref}
        style={styles.searchInput}
        keyboardType="default"
        placeholder="Type anything"
        returnKeyType="done"/>
```

And now on `<Button />`onPress, focus the `<TextInput />` like this:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.inputText.focus()}> 
    <Text>Click</Text>
</TouchableHightlight>
```

This should work. Let me know if there is any problem.